# Entity Framework setting Primary key using column names

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I'm using entity framework code first 5 with fluent mapping API.
I have a jointure table named 'ENTITY' with 3 columns

```
ENTITY1_ID int
ENTITY2_ID int
LEVEL   int
```

with associated model

```
public class ENTITY
{
   public virtual ENTITY1 ENTITY1 {get; set;}
   public virtual ENTITY2 ENTITY2 {get; set;}
   public virtual int LEVEL {get; set;}
}
```

where ENTITY1_ID and ENTITY2_ID are foreign keys toward two tables.
In the mapping code I've succeeded to declare the foreign keys without the need of adding associated properties to entity class:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.ENTITY1).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("ENTITY1_ID"));
this.HasRequired(t => t.ENTITY2).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("ENTITY2_ID"));
```

So I need to setup the primary key using column names only. using something like:

```
this.HasKey(new {"ENTITY1_ID", "ENTITY2_ID"});
```

I want to do that to avoid polluting my model with persistance related properties (ids ..).
Is it possible to do that on Entity Framework 5?

Answer (score -1):

If this is a many to many table then you can create this with attributes alone (no need for the fluent mappings)

```
public class Entity1
{
    public class Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

public class Entity2
{
    public class Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

And here is the joining table

```
public class EntityEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Entity1Id {get;set;}

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Entity2Id {get;set;}

    public int Level {get; set;}

    public virtual Entity1 Entity1 {get; set;}
    public virtual Entity2 Entity2 {get; set;}
}
```

That is all you need.  The rest of the 'magic' is done for you.

Remember to add these to your DbContext

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity1> Entity1s {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Entity2> Entity2s {get; set;}

    public DbSet<EntityEntity> EntityEntities {get; set;}        
}
```

Comment: Please read carefuly my question, I don't want to declare Entity1Id and Entity2Id.